# If I Unbind a TFS solution from TFS, is that local only or is the server changed

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm working on a POC to migrate our source control from TFS to Stash/GIT.  What I want to to is take a sample solution and, on my workstation, rebind it to Stash then check it in.

However, I do not want to mess up other users who may be looking at the same solution in TFS.

So my question is: If I unbind the solution from TFS on my workstation, does that affect the TFS server, assuming I do *not* commit that change to TFS but *do* checkin the solution to Stash/GIT?

Truth is I don't know what Unbind does behind the scenes so I'm proceeding with caution.

Comment: perfect!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unbind a solution from TFS won't affect the TFS server. The binding is responsible for providing source control functionality including various source control icons that indicate status in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Unbind only changes the solution file; it has no impact on the TFVC repository.